# Finding Tangent Plane Equation By The Basis

Tags: calculus

Find a basis and an equation to the tangent plane of

$$3x_1+x_2^3+2x_3+x_4^2=9$$
$$3x_1+3x_2-x_3-4x_4=1$$

at the point $(1,-1,3,-1)$

First we have to find a parameterization of the curve:

$$F(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=(3x_1+x_2^3+2x_3+x_4^2-9,3x_1+3x_2-x_3-4x_4-1)$$

Next we take the differential

\begin{pmatrix}
    3 & 3x_2^2 & 2 & 2x_4 \\
    3 & 3 & -1 & -4 \\
\end{pmatrix}

Which at the point $(1,-1,3,-1)$ is:

\begin{pmatrix}
    3 & 3 & 2 & -2 \\
    3 & 3 & -1 & -4 \\
\end{pmatrix}

Next we find a solution for the homogenous system:

$$(\frac{10}{9}t-s,s,-\frac{2}{3}t,t)$$ so the basis is:

$$(10,0,-6,9),(-1,1,0,0)$$

How do I find the equation of the tangent plane?

Answer (score 1):

As a vector space, the corresponding plane going through $0$ is given by

$$3x_1+3x_2+2x_3-2x_4=0$$

$$3x_1+3x_2-x_3-4x_4=0$$

but we want the actual tangent plane which should pass through $(1,-1,3,-1)$, so we need to translate it

therefore the tangent plane is given by

$$3(x_1-1)+3(x_2+1)+2(x_3-3)-2(x_4+1)=0$$

$$3(x_1-1)+3(x_2+1)-(x_3-3)-4(x_4+1)=0$$

i.e.

$$3x_1+3x_2+2x_3-2x_4=8$$

$$3x_1+3x_2-x_3-4x_4=1$$

this simplifies into

$$3x_1+3x_2+2x_3-2x_4=8$$

$$-3x_3-2x_4=-7$$

and to get a single equation, use $2x_4=7-3x_3$ and plug this into the first equation to obtain

$$3x_1+3x_2+5x_3=15$$